# Old robots.txt file not changing, can't update to the current robots.txt

Tags: google, robots.txt

While my wordpress website was in production, I created a robots.txt file to disallow everything. When the site was ready, I deleted the robots.txt file through cpanel and never thought much about it. Recently, I realized that the website was not showing up on google search results, upon further investigation, i realized that the old robots.txt file was still there (even though I can't locate the file in my root folder).

http://youngauthors.my/robots.txt

I inserted another robots.txt file in my root folder, this time with the allow option instead of disallow. But it doesn't update and still blocks google from accessing the site.

[image: Current robots.txt in root folder]

[image: Current robots.txt content]

[image: Old robots.txt as you type the url (this file was deleted a long time ago)]

[image: Even in the yoast editor it's the current file, but the url still brings up the old file]

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47258720/1591669)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete file **robots.txt**. WordPress is generating virtual robots.txt file, and Yoast SEO plugin (and other plugins too) allows you to customize it. But, if you have an actual **robots.txt** file, it will prevent virtual one to work.